# Running a project from android studio to galaxy S7 edge

Tags: android, sdk, libgdx

When I try to run my game on my S7 device several errors occur though the game can run on my desktop.

```
D/libGLESv2: DTS_GLAPI : DTS is not allowed for Package : com.game.game
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: GLThread 6535

The target Device does not support the 'run-as' command.

Instant Run requires that the android SDK for the API level of the 
device you are deploying to is installed. To use Instant Run open SDK
Manager and install the missing platform.
```

The menu screen of the game loads on my phone and then: Unfortunately, game has stopped.

Comment: what is installed version of android in your device S7 ??

Answer (score 2):

Open the sdk manager and install files for the version of android you galaxy s7 is on.

Comment: or do not use "instant run"